# Contentflow auto resize not working

Tags: imageflow, contentflow

Im using:
[Contentflow 1.0.2](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/)
jquery 1.6.1

I'm trying use Contentflow using reflection and with maximum width/height so it covers all the screen without any scroll bar vertically or horizontally.

This example shows exactly what I wanna do, but it uses ImageFlow (another plugin)
http://themes.themegoods.com/keres_wp/?page_id=459

At this point my config is like this and everything works fine except that Contentflow doesn't resize when I change the browser size.

```
var cf = new ContentFlow('contentFlow', {
                    reflectionColor: "#000000",
                    circularFlow: false,
                    startItem: 0,
                    fixItemSize: true,
                    scaleFactor:1.5
                });
```